# How to override global variable with values inside function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON object which has all data of input fields like below. I am creating UI by binding these JSON value.

```
inputs = [{"name": "Name", "type": "text", "value": null},
   {"name": "City", "type": "select", "options": this.cityArr, "value": null}]
```

I am calling API to get values of `this.cityArr` like below:

```
getCityList(){
this.dataService.getCityList().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.cityArr = data.city;
  console.log("city Arr" + this.cityArr);
});}
```

I got array of city in console but I can not get this list in `"options": this.cityArr` as I initialize cityArr like `cityArr:any = [];`
So how I can override global initialized variable with local values.
I have call `getCityList()` in `ngOnInit()` but it doesn't affect any change. Thanks in advance.

Below is the StackBlitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jez775?file=src%2Fapp%2F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this via this typescript :-

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  cityArr: any = [];

  inputs = [
    { name: "Name", type: "text", value: null },
    { name: "City", type: "select", options: this.cityArr, value: null }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCityList();
  }

  getCityList() {
    this.cityArr = ["Mumbai", "Benglore", "Chennai"];
    this.inputs[1].options = this.cityArr;
  }
}
```

and template :-

```
<div *ngFor="let input of inputs">
  <input *ngIf="input.type == 'text'" type={{input.type}} value={{input.value}}/>
  <select *ngIf="input.type == 'select'">
    <option *ngFor="let option of input?.options">{{option}}</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpampb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: what should I put in options inside inputs json. I have tried {"name": "City", "type": "select", "options": "", "value": null} with your answer but it is not worked.

Comment: put null there to make it work. if it still doesn't can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: I have created stackblitz. Please look into it - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jez775?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html